what data to be sent back to client for a zero knowledge app?
I’m building an app like Bitwarden, where the server has zero knowledge of user data. Here’s the plan:
Key Generation and Storage:
When a user signs up:
A public key and private key pair are generated.
A symmetric key is derived from the user's password + salt.
Database Storage:
Hashed password (using something secure like bcrypt).
Encrypted private key (encrypted with the symmetric key).
Public key.
Salt.
Response to Client:
A JWT token for auth.
The salt.
The public key.
The encrypted private key.
The client uses the password + salt to derive the symmetric key, decrypts the private key, and stores it securely.
Why This Approach?
The server doesn’t know the user's plaintext password or private key.
Private key handling is pushed to the client, making the app "zero-knowledge."
Am I Missing Anything?
I think this works, but is there a better way to do this? Should I tweak anything to make it more secure?

https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/36960 and https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1566/36960
